# Bypassing Microsoft Intune Company Portal to access Exchange email and contacts?

Tags: contacts, email, exchange, active-sync, microsoft-intune

I used to have Outlook for Android installed on my personal mobile to access my work email which runs on Office 365. I reinstalled it recently only to find that now I have to install Microsoft Intune Company Portal and make it a device administrator to proceed with logging in (I couldn't get around it by restoring from a Titanium Backup of when I had it installed before).

I think this is somewhat overkill when all the same information and more can be accessed via a web browser anyway, so I don't want to give Microsoft almost total control of my phone just to get my work email and contacts if I can avoid it.

I tried the app [Nine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ninefolders.hd3) because I heard that it could set the security policies to be at the app level instead of the device lever, but when I logged in, I still got nothing except one email telling me I had to install Intune. The same thing happened with the Gmail app and Mailwise, but on those, I could see an empty version of my folder directory.

Somehow logging in through [Cloudmagic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudmagic.mail) was actually seamless as far as grabbing my email, but it has no support yet for syncing contacts between Exchange and the device. I actually wanted the contacts *more* than the email in order to get some mobile numbers.

So, what's the best way to work around Intune? Installing it but neutering it via Xprivacy or another permissions manager? Finding another app that will do for contacts what Cloudmagic did for email? I'm less concerned about adding my calendar.

Comment: You can try these other two Xposed modules: 1. [Security Bypass for Company Portal](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.hugesoft.sbpforcp) This module can bypass the Intune Company Portal. 2. [Exchange Bypass For Lollipop](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.wudi.ebpforl) This app can bypass the official Gmail client and Outlook app. Both of these modules are based on the Xposed framework and must be installed on a rooted device.